# GNU screen custom key bindings format

Tags: key-bindings, gnu-screen, screenrc

I am trying to add key bindings to the .screenrc file for making a lot of things easier. So far I have understood the following pattern

```
bindkey "^k" eval "copy" "stuff k"    # enter copy mode and move up one line
```

Here **^** corresponds to the Ctrl key, **eval** is evaluate while **"copy"** signifies entry into the copy mode. **stuff**, I am assuming, is like an escape character which helps screen understand that k is a command inside copy mode. Now I can enter the copy mode with `<Ctrl-k>` and escape it using any unused key like ] or Esc.

I want to understand the key binding format a little better and need some source like `:h keycodes` in VIM which shows all the possible key bindings that VIM understands.

Is there a command or help page that can tell me what key bindings screen can understand? For example, how do we know how screen understands PageUp/PageDown so that we can map it to some function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Input Translation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_62.html) section of the manpage. There's a table there with all the termcap names for the keys, which you can use like `bindkey -k k5 other` (this binds the F5 key to the `other` command for toggling between active windows).

Also, look at the `bind` command, which binds keys which are entered from command mode (after pressing `Ctrl-a`).

The `stuff` command sends its arguments as though the user typed them at the prompt. I have used this in the past to control multiple shells on multiple machines by "stuffing" keystrokes into all my windows.